# Will std::ceil(int_x / std::log2(int_y)) always produce accurate results?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Will `std::ceil(int_x / std::log2(int_y))` always produce accurate results? Or can floating point precision issues cause this to be off by one for some values of `x` and `y`?

Edit: I'm specifically looking for the simplest way I can *accurately* calculate `ceil(x * 8 / log2(y))` for integer values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: The C++ standard does not require “accurate” results for this. What is the context—why are you trying to do this calculation?

Comment: Generally, all floating-point operations will suffer from precision and rounding issues.

Comment: if you just want to find how many bits are required to store a number then there are functions to do that which are faster and more accurate https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width

Comment: @EricPostpischil the context is I need to calculate `std::ceil((x * 8) / std::log2(y))` and if I get `std::ceil((x * 8) / std::log2(y)) - 1` or `std::ceil((x * 8) / std::log2(y)) + 1` I'm going to have a bad day.

Comment: @AlanBirtles `bit_width` calculates `floor(log2(x))+1`

Comment: As soon as you use floating point, you open the door for imprecise results - in your case both the calculation of `log2()` and the floating point division potentially introduce/propagate a rounding error of some form.   Depending on what your expectations are, see if you can work out a way to compute your intended result using some form of integer arithmetic (possibly bitwise operations).

Comment: You say that you need to do that calculation, but *why* do you need to do it? What are you using the result for? What actual and underlying problem is that calculation and its result supposed to solve? Why is the precision so important? Right now your question unfortunately is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No. This is not and XY problem. Even if you had an alternative solution for my Y-problem I still want the answer to this X-problem.

Comment: Re “I'm specifically looking for the simplest way I can *accurately* calculate `ceil(x * 8 / log2(y))` for integer values of `x` and `y`”: No, you are not. If that were truly the actual problem, you would need arbitrary precision arithmetic, since the potential integer values of x and y are unbounded. In reality, there is some practical problem you are trying to solve, and you are not being forthcoming about the details. Providing context can help other people elucidate the parameters and find practical solutions. Practical answers might differ considerably depending on bounds on x and y.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can read my comment to Someprogrammerdude. You don't need to know what I am using this for because I want the solution to this problem regardless of how it gets used. If you want me to narrow the requirements then assume that `x` is no larger than a 32-bit uint and `y` is relatively small, say less than 10,000.

Comment: That leaves no alternatives, the only possible answer can then be  this: It's impossible. Your solution can't work. And there's nothing more we can do about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That is absurd. Direct use of the standard library functions is not the only way to do mathematical calculations. Nor is direct use of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, wow. `ciel(log2(x))` is an uncomputable number. I had no idea. Maybe you should let the mathematics community know.

Comment: Keep in mind you are asking people for free labor. Stack Overflow is a community. It is not a free service for work-on-demand, and nobody owes you an answer. Even if evaluating ceil(8x/log2(y)) is the principal problem to be solved, people are curious about how it arises. For some it may be learning opportunity, for some it may be a pleasant pastime, for some the context may, even if it does not reveal another problem to be solved instead, provide insight into approaches. By withholding information, you are not participating positively in the community, and the votes reflect that…

Comment: … Being cagey about the context and withholding information can arouse dislike and even distrust. You want something for free. Give something in return.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't care. I found an alternative solution to my Y problem that doesn't require this, but the question still stands. There will inevitably be some context in which calculating the ceiling of a base2 logarithm *is* necessary and I have received little actuall advice because of a bunch of busybodies who were more concerned with looking as though they are intelligent enough to have heard of the 'XY problem' than they were to simply answer (assuming they have the ability) a question on a questions and answers website.

Comment: @Chris_F for what range of `int_y` does this need to work [1...INT_MAX] or something narrower?  Perhaps a fixed range like [1... 1,000,000,000]?

Comment: @Chris_F  I am confident that, yes, there is a way, but need more info, like what is the range of `x` as well as `y`.  ( `y >= 2` is required)  Do you really needs `x` from [INT_MIN to INT_MAX]`?

Answer (score 4):

> Will std::ceil(int_x / std::log2(int_y)) always produce accurate results?

No, not in the sense that the result will correspond with the result expected of the equivalent expression in the real numbers, even if all values (including intermediate ones) are in range of their types.

> Or can floating point precision issues cause this to be off by one for some values of x and y?

It can be off by any number. Aside from floating-point representation problems, there are no standard guarantees on the accuracy of `std::log2`. It doesn't need to be e.g. one of the two closest representable values from the mathematical exact result. You'll have to look into a documentation of your particular C standard library implementation for that.

> I'm specifically looking for the simplest way I can accurately calculate

C++20 introduced the [`<bit>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) with functions for (unsigned) integral types that e.g. count bits, ceil/floor to powers of two, find the highest set bit index, etc. These are not floating-point based and have accurate behavior. You'll probably want to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

> Will `std::ceil(int_x / std::log2(int_y))` always produce accurate results?

No. Take `int_x = 935179272; int_y = 47`, and this expression will not produce the expected result (with binary64 `double`) when replacing `std::log2` and `/` with real-valued log<sub>2</sub> and real division.

Here's a "simple" but not very performant way to calculate this value. It calculates the upper and lower bounds for `ceil(x / log2(y))` and returns them if they are equal, otherwise it recalculates at a higher precision (using MPFR. You might find it easier to use the Boost.Multiprecision binding):

```cpp
#include <mpfr.h>

unsigned calculate(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    mp_prec_t prec = 52;

    mpfr_t lo, hi;
    mpfr_init2(lo, prec);
    mpfr_init2(hi, prec);
    unsigned result;

    while (true) {
        mpfr_set_ui(lo, y, MPFR_RNDN);

        int rounding = mpfr_log2(lo, lo, MPFR_RNDD);
        mpfr_set(hi, lo, MPFR_RNDN);
        if (rounding < 0) {
            // Rounded down, the upper bound for log2(y) is the next number
            mpfr_nextabove(hi);
        }

        mpfr_ui_div(hi, x, hi, MPFR_RNDD);
        result = mpfr_get_ui(hi, MPFR_RNDU);  // Lower bound of ceil(x / log2(y))
        mpfr_ui_div(lo, x, lo, MPFR_RNDU);
        unsigned result_hi = mpfr_get_ui(lo, MPFR_RNDU);  // Upper bound
        if (result == result_hi)
            break;

        prec *= 2;
        mpfr_set_prec(lo, prec);
        mpfr_set_prec(hi, prec);
    }

    mpfr_clear(hi);
    mpfr_clear(lo);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the smallest integer `n` with `n>=x/log2(y)` is equivalent to finding the smallest integer `n` with `y^n>=2^x` (assuming `y>1`, of course). If `y^n` is close to a power of two, you may need to calculate this expression with a precision close to `x` bits. If you calculated something close to the exact result, you could calculate `y^n` for two or three values with big integer math and take the smallest `n` which is big enough.